# I am trying to make an invisible pig that I can put a lead on. How?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

In Java, I have been trying to make a pig turn invisible. I have tried potions but they wear off too fast and become useless. I want to be able to put a lead on it.

If possible, I'd like the pig to already be invisible when it's summoned.

Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 1):

`/give @s pig_spawn_egg{EntityTag:{Silent:1b,Invulnerable:1b,PersistenceRequired:1b,NoAI:1b,ActiveEffects:[{Id:14b,Amplifier:1b,Duration:20000000,ShowParticles:0b}]}} 1`

You can rely on mcstacker.net for lots of things using commands. This will give you a pig spawn egg that is silent, unkillable, doesn't despawn, and doesn't move. It also has the invisibility effect, and doesn't show the invisibility particles.